# Universal solution for storing CGPoint in NSArray in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray, cgpoint

I have a class that I would like to share between a Cocoa and Cocoa Touch applications. This class calculates various `CGPoint`s and stores them in an array. In Cocoa there's `[NSValue valueWithPoint]`. In Cocoa Touch there's `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint]`.

Is there any solution that would allow me to bypass using these framework-specific methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a category on `NSValue` in order to add the `valueWithCGPoint:` and `CGPointValue` methods to Cocoa.

```
#if ! TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@interface NSValue (MyCGPointAddition)
+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point;
- (CGPoint)CGPointValue;
@end
#endif
```

```
#if ! TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@implementation NSValue (MyCGPointAddition)
+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    return [self valueWithPoint:NSPointFromCGPoint(point)];
}
- (CGPoint)CGPointValue {
    return NSPointToCGPoint([self pointValue]);
}
@end
#endif
```

Or you may use `valueWithBytes:objCType:` and `getValue:`.

```
CGPoint point = {10, 10};
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&point objCType:@encode(CGPoint)];
// ...
[value getValue:&point];
```

Comment: Awesome! I used the last suggestion. With a category I would still have to explicitly #import one the frameworks, which I wanted to avoid. Thanks.